# How to manage large number of ports?

Tags: linux, docker, port

I'm running a lot of services (most of them are docker-managed). I struggle with managing port numbers for all of them. The problem arises when I want to spin a new e.g. HTTP server. I have to look for a port number that hasn't been already taken by other services. Currently, when I want to spin a new server, I look for all taken ports in `docker ps` if for example taken ports are 8001, 8002, 8003,...8051, then I assign port 8052. It works fine until some service becomes temporarily dead, thus doesn't show up in `docker ps`, I assign its port to new service, and when the old one is restored I have ports collision.

I'm already using Nginx for reverse proxy to expose my servers to public network. But this doesn't solve my problem. I still have to somehow find the latest unused port number, and neither `nginx.conf` nor `docker ps` is single-source-of-truth in this situation.

Is there any solution for managing ports? Some registry?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider the question was closed on SO, with the suggestion that it was more appropriate for a site discussing professional server and networking questions.

Answer (score 2):

Let Docker find a free port for you when you create the container.

From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#connect-using-network-port-mapping):

> you may specify a range of host ports to bind a container port to that is different than the default ephemeral port range:
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d -p 8000-9000:5000 training/webapp python app.py
> ```
>
> This would bind port 5000 in the container to a randomly available port between 8000 and 9000 on the host.

You can get the exposed port afterwards with `docker inspect`, for example like this:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ range .HostConfig.PortBindings }}{{ range . }}{{ . }}{{ end }}{{ end }}' container
{127.0.0.1 8095}
```

Configuration of my test container:

```
"PortBindings": {
    "8080/tcp": [
        {
            "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
            "HostPort": "8095"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you go that way, you can use `docker port $container 8080` to get the published port instead of the formatted inspect command. This still involves added complexity outside of docker to map external references to the current port used by docker, so I've only ever seen it used for dynamic and scripted test environments.

Answer (score 0):

[Moving my answer over from the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65282099/596285)

With http based services, this is easier done with a reverse proxy. You have one service listening on port 80/443, and then using a wildcard dns to map all hostnames to the docker host you can access each service with a unique hostname. You can also use path based routing, but that gets more challenging with the deployed app isn't written with relative paths.

Example reverse proxies include nginx, haproxy, and traefik. My preference is traefik since it is designed to automatically reconfigure based on running containers. These proxies run in docker, use a shared docker network, and only the proxy has a published port, the rest of the services are accessed over the docker network through the proxy.

Note that this proxy is separate from the proxy you may have running external to docker. Both can coexist if you have other external requests going to other servers on the network. For all requests to containers on the docker host, the external proxy sends requests to the docker based proxy.

Comment: For the downvoter, please let me know how I can improve this answer.

Comment: You could start by actually addressing the question, which is "how do I find a free port for the container I want to start". The OP states that they are already using a reverse proxy.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider OP states that they are using a reverse proxy outside of docker, trying to point to a number of services in docker each listening on a separate published port. The standard model is to have a reverse proxy running **inside of docker**, removing the need to publish and track ports, which is an alternate way to manage the issue.

Comment: @BMitch your answer is very interesting. I will try it, and if it actually solves my problem I will accept it. How about non-http services ?

Comment: @StanislawBaranski To share a single port to multiple services, you need a proxy at L7 of the network stack, inspecting the application and forwarding to the appropriate destination. This is well established for HTTP, and traefik also does this for TLS connections using SNI to non-HTTP services, but often you're left managing those ports individually if you can't find a specific L7 proxy for the protocol.